# difference between read out of and read out

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between read out and read out of, for example in the sentences :

He read out the names on the list. 
and

She read out of the book.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

*Read out* means you read something out loud for everyone to hear.

> Read out the names so that we can all hear.

*Read out of* the book means to use the book as a source, to read a portion from the book( Thanks Fumble Fingers).

> Are you inventing your story or reading out of/from the book?

Comment: There aren't many contexts where you'd need present tense for the *use a book as a source of information* sense, but it's common enough in the past tense: *How do you know that? I read it **in** a book*. I don't think *[to read] **out of*** works for that sense. So far as I can see, if you use ***out*** at all it [nearly?] always implies reading out loud - where including ***of*** implies that you're only reading a *portion*, not the entire text.